# How should I install Core Lightning if my VPS won't let me use pip install?

Tags: python, core-lightning, compiling, installation

I tried to install Core Lightning on a Ubuntu Digital Ocean droplet using these [installation instructions](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/getting-started/getting-started/installation.md#to-build-on-ubuntu) and it won't let me `pip install` anything giving me an error `externally-managed-environment`. Should I just use poetry instead or is there a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openoms suggested this [fix](https://github.com/raspiblitz/raspiblitz/blob/3c207ac909fc0654a282fe5862bfeceed47358e6/build_sdcard.sh#L380-L383) on Telegram to keep using pip:

> sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.*/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED

Christian Decker added some context around Core Lightning's use of Python in its build process:

> Python is not a runtime dependency, which is why it is not
> being listed as a direct dependency, but we use it for a variety of
> build steps. The error you received is because the pip environment is
> owned by root since you installed it via the package manager. If you
> want to install the build dependencies we strongly suggest using a
> virtualenv. Steps on how to set that up depend on the OS, and your
> Python setup, hence why it is left undocumented (it's not CLN
> specific, and any documentation on how to create virtualenvs would
> bitrot, and we can't be authoritative anyway, since it is an external
> project). We just need to find a good point to cut off the long tail,
> and for venv that was the place that felt right.
>
> Python dependency management grew quite organically, which explains the mess of different ideas and models being mixed. Usually you have the system environment, which you can extend through a user environment that gets overlaid. This does not work however if a user package clashes with a system package. We seem to rely on rather recent package versions, that may clash, causing this error. A virtualenv (initialized with `--no-site-packages`) creates a blank page without weird combinations of system and user packages.

Answer (score 1):

Check environment variables: Some Docker containers or cloud environments might restrict pip commands. Ensure variables like PIP_NO_INDEX or PIP_DISABLE_PYPI are not set to restrict package installations.
Check user permissions: You may need root or sudo privileges to use pip install. Try using sudo pip install if appropriate.
Isolate the issue: Create a new virtual environment and try installing Core Lightning there. This helps identify if the issue is specific to your current environment.
Consider alternative package managers: If pip continues to cause issues, try installing dependencies using apt or other package managers compatible with your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the issue are changes introduced recently in Python and not the policy of your VPS. There are two solutions for [this](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/7103):

**1.** Install Python dependencies with a package manager like `apt`, e.g. `apt install -y python3-mako python3-poetry`.

**2.** Use `--break-system-packages` flag for pip, e.g. `pip install --user poetry --break-system-packages`.

The first option requires you to act as `root`, the second does not.